# How to use a double 7 segment with atmega32

Tags: c, atmega, embedded, 7segmentdisplay

I'm learning Embedded Systems and how to use ATMEGA32 MCU.
Now I'm trying to display a fractional number to the 7 segment but it just won't display!
[image: 7SEG Displaying nothing]

But if I move the handle of the potentiometer -The voltage on its middle pin I'm trying to display - it displays a weird bar.

[image: 7SEG Displaying bar]

However if I forget about doing the decimal thing and just display the integer and replace the double 7SEG with an ordinary one, it works. Meaning that the MCU reads the value correctly.

If I add a delay in the code.

It displays the numbers momentarily before removing them.

So I guess for whatever reason it still alters the second 7SEG even if the code is commanding it to alter the first only and vice versa.

What am I missing here?

Edit: Here's the code:

```
    void SvnSEG_Disp(float num) {
        num_int = (uint8_t)num; // Will take values from Zero to 5
        after_point = (num - (uint8_t)num)*10; // Will take values from Zero to 9
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD5); // Set PD5 to Zero. Use first 7SEG
        PORTD |= (1 << PD6);  // Set PD6 to One. Don't use second 7SEG
        PORTD |= (1 << PD4);  // Set PD4 turning on the Decimal point.
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD0); // Set PD0 to 0
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD1); // Set PD1 to 0
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD2); // Set PD2 to 0
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD3); // Set PD3 to 0 


        PORTD |= num_int; // Set the lower 4 bits of Port D (PD0 - PD3) to the bits of the number.

        PORTD |= (1 << PD5); // Set PD5 to One. Don't use first 7SEG
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD6); // Set PD6 to Zero. Use second 7SEG
        PORTD |= (1 << PD4); // Set PD4 turning on the Decimal point.
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD0); // Set PD0 to 0
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD1); // Set PD1 to 0
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD2); // Set PD2 to 0
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PD3); // Set PD3 to 0


        PORTD |= after_point; // Set the lower 4 bits of Port D (PD0 - PD3) to the bits of the number.

   }
```

Comment: Exactly which 'double 7SEG' display did you choose? (eg. 7SEG-MPX2-CA-BLUE)

Comment: you made me laugh ... you are trying to light up a 7 segment display ... when one of the segments finally lights, you call it a "weird bar" ... lol ... +1 for that

Comment: @BruceAbbott 7SEG-MPX2-CC-BLUE

Comment: @jsotola I want a number not a bar.

Comment: review the 4511 data sheet.  ... it is possible that you have some of the pin values incorrectly set

Comment: this [link](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/4511-BCD-to-7-segment-display-decoder-circuit.php) shows how to connect the 4511 bcd to 7segment latch

Comment: in general, and to keep the code simple, the code needs to contain a table of what bits need to be ON/OFF for each desired digit displayed.  Then the code is passed a value and that value is used to select the desired entry from the table.  Then the code sets the 4 output port bits per that entry from the table

Comment: because the changing of the individual bits will result in flashing on the 7segment LCDs, strongly suggest building the whole port value as an image in memory, then writing the whole byte as a single I/O

Comment: Please post a link to the data sheet for the 7SEG-MPX2-CC-BLUE.

Comment: shouldn't there be connections to the dual 7segment chip, for power and ground?

Comment: the passed in value is a `float` so to obtain a whole number, use the `floor()` function and assign the result to a word then perform a modulo 10 to obtain the least significant digit.  To obtain the fraction, multiply by 10.0f then use the `floor()` function then perform a modulo 10.  to obtain the value to set the bcd bits, use a table with 10 entries and use the result of the above calculations to index into that table to obtain the value to set into the bcd bits

Comment: @jsotola No the 4511 pins are set up correctly.

Comment: @user3629249 I'll see the link thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3629249 But this is not needed using this particular BCD, the binary representation of the number I want displayed will give the right combination of the ON/OFF bits to be given to the BCD.

Comment: @user3629249 The only datasheet I could find: https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjiy_jRiYrZAhWR_aQKHdeQB4cQFghYMAs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcategory.alldatasheet.com%2Findex.jsp%3FsSearchword%3D7%2520SEG-MPX2-CA%2520%2520blue&usg=AOvVaw184ar7ZoqYAQRY8rZ1Jorj

Comment: @user3629249 It is a simulation many things doesn't need the power/ground thing.

Comment: @user3629249 But the way I used to obtain the digit and the fraction, works right? 

I added a delay in the code the numbers shown are right, still the 7SEG goes on and off after each delay.

Comment: if i was trying to make the display work, i would start with the display and a few switches.  i would manually switch inputs `1` and `2` and at least three of the others.  ... that would tell me what i have to do with the input pins to make the display work. ... then move to manually switching the inputs to U2

Answer (score 1):

One thing about 7 segment displays is that they have no memory. Typically the way to control more than one is to:

display on digit 1 -> switch to digit 2 -> display on digit 2 -> switch to digit 1 -> display on digit 1 -> switch to digit 2 -> and so on.

You are setting digit 1, and then switching to digit 2 (so digit 1 is now off) and stopping after that.

You should constantly cycle between the digits to keep all of them on. If you do this fast enough it will appear like they are both always on.

The "weird bar" you are seeing looks like the color-inverted digit 0. I generally suggest applying a mask to the values you write to PORTD to make sure you are actually only changing bits 0-3. Do something like this:

```
PORTD &= ~0xF;      // Clear bits 0-3
PORTD |= num & 0xF; // Write bits 0-3
```

Comment: I will try the mask thing.

Comment: But if I use a loop inside in the function, well, the MCU will not do anything else. 

Anyways the function is called in the While(1) block so it should be constantly lit? I guees it doesn't have the time to be lit.

Comment: "But if I use a loop inside in the function, well, the MCU will not do anything else." - what else does your code need to do?

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm, you **could** always use a timer interrupt to trigger the digit change. I would let them stay lit for a little bit at least though.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Calculate the number from the value of the ADC then show it.

Comment: @Catsunami But that won't help anything. If I change the digit on one 7SEG the other will go off. I used the delay and it didn't help. It made each 7SEG alternate between on/off only. But both didn't display simultaneously the numbers.

Comment: As was mentioned elsewhere, the display(s) have no memory, and only one can be 'on' at a time.  That is why the need to be powering each display in quick succession.  Strongly suggest using a timer interrupt to repeatedly power each display in quick succession

Comment: "It made each 7SEG alternate between on/off only." - that's what you want. If they alternate fast enough it will look like they are both on together (on _real_ hardware, perhaps not in a simulator!). "Calculate the number from the value of the ADC then show it. " - this may take a few milliseconds. Adjust your delays to include this time and the two digits should have equal brightness.

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm, yes, as I mentioned in my answer, there is **no** way they will both be on at the same time. You need to cycle between the two quickly. I suggest using real hardware as BruceAbbott has suggested.